# Xamarin Android: Application crashes (missing libmonosgen-2.0.so)

Tags: android, xamarin, crash

Xamarin Studio 5.10.3 (build 27)

Device: Xiaomi Mi4c (Android 5.1)

I have a basic template of Android application, I'm trying to debug application. It crashes...

Installed packages:

```
Mono.Android.DebugRuntime
Mono.Android.Platform.ApiLevel_19
```

I tried:

```
adb uninstall Mono.Android.DebugRuntime
```

And then install application using IDE or:

```
MSBuild /t:Install YourProject.csproj
```

but with no success.

There is a logcat:

```
I/ActivityManager( 1086): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.rinart73.niceapp/md579058f2ed4a300dd704bd6ac0c3e80e0.MainActivity bnds=[571,978][763,1170]} from uid 10020 on display 0
V/WindowManager( 1086): addAppToken: AppWindowToken{2f39fa16 token=Token{4cf8331 ActivityRecord{3c2d63d8 u0 com.rinart73.niceapp/md579058f2ed4a300dd704bd6ac0c3e80e0.MainActivity t4972}}} to stack=1 task=4972 at 0
V/WindowManager( 1086): Adding window Window{3b68216d u0 Starting com.rinart73.niceapp} at 10 of 19 (after Window{391a3ce7 u0 org.coolreader/org.coolreader.CoolReader})
I/ActivityManager( 1086): Start proc 18762:com.rinart73.niceapp/u0a250 for activity com.rinart73.niceapp/md579058f2ed4a300dd704bd6ac0c3e80e0.MainActivity
D/WhetstoneService( 5319): set foreground process size 1  pid:18762pacakgeName:com.rinart73.niceapp
W/WhetstoneService( 5319): {WhetstonePackageInfo#PacakgeName:com.rinart73.niceappFlag:1073742848 [,SOFT_RESET] Type:0[] }not support ZRAM
D/PowerKeeperEventLogManager( 5625): notifyForegroundCompomentChanged ComponentInfo{com.rinart73.niceapp/md579058f2ed4a300dd704bd6ac0c3e80e0.MainActivity}
W/monodroid(18762): Using override path: /data/data/com.rinart73.niceapp/files/.override
W/monodroid(18762): Using override path: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.rinart73.niceapp/files/.override
W/monodroid(18762): Trying to load sgen from: /data/data/com.rinart73.niceapp/files/.override/libmonosgen-2.0.so
W/monodroid(18762): Trying to load sgen from: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.rinart73.niceapp/files/.override/libmonosgen-2.0.so
W/monodroid(18762): Trying to load sgen from: /data/data/com.rinart73.niceapp/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so
F/monodroid(18762): cannot find libmonosgen-2.0.so in override_dir: /data/data/com.rinart73.niceapp/files/.override, app_libdir: /data/data/com.rinart73.niceapp/lib nor in previously printed locations.
I/ActivityManager( 1086): Process com.rinart73.niceapp (pid 18762) has died
W/WhetstoneService( 5319): {WhetstonePackageInfo#PacakgeName:com.rinart73.niceappFlag:1073742848 [,SOFT_RESET] Type:0[] }not support ZRAM
I/ActivityManager( 1086): Start proc 18797:com.rinart73.niceapp/u0a250 for activity com.rinart73.niceapp/md579058f2ed4a300dd704bd6ac0c3e80e0.MainActivity
D/PowerKeeperEventLogManager( 5625): notifyForegroundCompomentChanged ComponentInfo{com.rinart73.niceapp/md579058f2ed4a300dd704bd6ac0c3e80e0.MainActivity}
W/monodroid(18797): Using override path: /data/data/com.rinart73.niceapp/files/.override
W/monodroid(18797): Using override path: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.rinart73.niceapp/files/.override
W/monodroid(18797): Trying to load sgen from: /data/data/com.rinart73.niceapp/files/.override/libmonosgen-2.0.so
W/monodroid(18797): Trying to load sgen from: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.rinart73.niceapp/files/.override/libmonosgen-2.0.so
W/monodroid(18797): Trying to load sgen from: /data/data/com.rinart73.niceapp/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so
F/monodroid(18797): cannot find libmonosgen-2.0.so in override_dir: /data/data/com.rinart73.niceapp/files/.override, app_libdir: /data/data/com.rinart73.niceapp/lib nor in previously printed locations.
I/ActivityManager( 1086): Process com.rinart73.niceapp (pid 18797) has died
W/WhetstoneService( 5319): {WhetstonePackageInfo#PacakgeName:com.rinart73.niceappFlag:1073742848 [,SOFT_RESET] Type:0[] }not support ZRAM
I/ActivityManager( 1086): Start proc 18833:com.rinart73.niceapp/u0a250 for activity com.rinart73.niceapp/md579058f2ed4a300dd704bd6ac0c3e80e0.MainActivity
D/PowerKeeperEventLogManager( 5625): notifyForegroundCompomentChanged ComponentInfo{com.rinart73.niceapp/md579058f2ed4a300dd704bd6ac0c3e80e0.MainActivity}
W/monodroid(18833): Using override path: /data/data/com.rinart73.niceapp/files/.override
W/monodroid(18833): Using override path: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.rinart73.niceapp/files/.override
W/monodroid(18833): Trying to load sgen from: /data/data/com.rinart73.niceapp/files/.override/libmonosgen-2.0.so
W/monodroid(18833): Trying to load sgen from: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.rinart73.niceapp/files/.override/libmonosgen-2.0.so
W/monodroid(18833): Trying to load sgen from: /data/data/com.rinart73.niceapp/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so
F/monodroid(18833): cannot find libmonosgen-2.0.so in override_dir: /data/data/com.rinart73.niceapp/files/.override, app_libdir: /data/data/com.rinart73.niceapp/lib nor in previously printed locations.
I/ActivityManager( 1086): Process com.rinart73.niceapp (pid 18833) has died
W/ActivityManager( 1086): Force removing ActivityRecord{3c2d63d8 u0 com.rinart73.niceapp/md579058f2ed4a300dd704bd6ac0c3e80e0.MainActivity t4972}: app died, no saved state
```

**Logcat after Jon Douglas advice:**

```
W/monodroid(13078): Trying to load sgen from: /data/data/com.rinart73.niceapp/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
W/monodroid(13078): Trying to load sgen from: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.rinart73.niceapp/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
W/monodroid(13078): Trying to load sgen from: /data/data/com.rinart73.niceapp/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so
W/monodroid(13078): Trying to load sgen from: /data/data/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime/lib/libmonosgen-64bit-2.0.so
W/monodroid(13078): Trying to load sgen from: /system/lib64/libmonosgen-2.0.so
F/monodroid(13078): cannot find libmonosgen-2.0.so in override_dir: /data/data/com.rinart73.niceapp/files/.__override__, app_libdir: /data/data/com.rinart73.niceapp/lib nor in previously printed locations.
W/monodroid(13112): Trying to load sgen from: /data/data/com.rinart73.niceapp/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
W/monodroid(13112): Trying to load sgen from: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.rinart73.niceapp/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
W/monodroid(13112): Trying to load sgen from: /data/data/com.rinart73.niceapp/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so
W/monodroid(13112): Trying to load sgen from: /data/data/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime/lib/libmonosgen-64bit-2.0.so
W/monodroid(13112): Trying to load sgen from: /system/lib64/libmonosgen-2.0.so
F/monodroid(13112): cannot find libmonosgen-2.0.so in override_dir: /data/data/com.rinart73.niceapp/files/.__override__, app_libdir: /data/data/com.rinart73.niceapp/lib nor in previously printed locations.
W/monodroid(13151): Trying to load sgen from: /data/data/com.rinart73.niceapp/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
W/monodroid(13151): Trying to load sgen from: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.rinart73.niceapp/files/.__override__/libmonosgen-2.0.so
W/monodroid(13151): Trying to load sgen from: /data/data/com.rinart73.niceapp/lib/libmonosgen-2.0.so
W/monodroid(13151): Trying to load sgen from: /data/data/Mono.Android.DebugRuntime/lib/libmonosgen-64bit-2.0.so
W/monodroid(13151): Trying to load sgen from: /system/lib64/libmonosgen-2.0.so
F/monodroid(13151): cannot find libmonosgen-2.0.so in override_dir: /data/data/com.rinart73.niceapp/files/.__override__, app_libdir: /data/data/com.rinart73.niceapp/lib nor in previously printed locations.
```

Comment: did you use libmonosgen-2.0.so in your armeabi folder ?

Comment: I have only a symlink to a /data/app-libs/ (empty folder)? Can I just compile a release build and move libmonosgen from it to /data/app-libs? And then Debug as usual? Or it's different for a debug?

Comment: I would recommend removing everything via `adb uninstall <package name>` (App, Runtime). You should then clean your project and remove the obj/bin folders.

Finally use the IDE to deploy your debug build and ensure that the respective application is deploying the `libmonosgen-2.0` lib where it's being searched for in your `adb logcat`.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. Attached a new logcat

Comment: @user64675 did you find a solution to this?

Comment: try to set property <AndroidUseSharedRuntime> to False in your .csproj file

Answer (score 6):

For me the fix was to untick "Use Shared Runtime" in the Android Options section of the .csproj file's property window.

I am assuming that this error is happening on a device that has previously had other Xamarin debug apps installed on it. If that is the case and you select "Use Shared Runtime" then it is possible that the version of Xamarin Runtime you have already installed on the device is not compatible with the version of Xamarin Runtime needed by the app.

I had the same problem except that my app was working properly on one phone and crashing on startup with another phone. The phone where it was working was a clean device with no other Xamarin debug apps and therefore it had to install the correct runtime the first time. The device crashing had other old apps installed.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an older issue, but just came across it updating from android 9 to 10. I had to change the Android Package Format from "apk" to "bundle".